# Reflect changes from Trigger after Update

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a SQL Server table with database Trigger (Update) where sometimes a value is changed depending on the Update values. I know how to reflect changes if there a coumputed columns like setting "ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate":

```
builder.Entity<PDBIntern.Models.PDB.Pfuscherakt>()
                .Property(p => p.Aktenzahl)                
                .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
```

but if I set ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate the generated Update statement exclude this column. How to reflect changes from Trigger and also include this coumn in the result (Select after Update)

Or is there a possibility to define the columns which EF generates after update statement to reflect changes in the table?

regards Robert

Answer (score 0):

Your ef code does not know what your trigger has done. How could it?
Try refreshing your context before any operation eg. update

```
await dbContext.Entry(PDBIntern.Models.PDB.Pfuscherakt).ReloadAsync();
```

Comment: I know that - my question was in that direction that if I mark a column as ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate it will be into the immediately SELECT after update to reflect the coumputed column changes - is there a possibility to define the columns into this SELECT without setting ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate?

with ReloadAsync it is another SELECT to the database after the update...